# Examples of non-equivariant momentum maps

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry

What are examples of non-equivariant momentum maps?

Off the top of my hat, I know about the following examples:

- the action of translations of a symplectic vector space (yielding the Heisenberg group as a central extension),
- the action of the group of Galilean transformations on $\mathbb R^6$ and
- certain actions of diffeomorphism groups (e.g. the one constructing the Virasoro group, or in fluid dynamics).

Are there more interesting classes of examples?

Comment: Are you asking for examples of Hamiltonian actions that are not Poisson (i.e., Hamiltonian actions for which there is *no choice* of an equivariant momentum mapping), or are you asking for examples of Poisson actions for which there is an 'interesting' momentum mapping that happens not to be equivariant?

Comment: I'm mostly looking for examples of Hamiltonian actions whose non-equivariance cocycle is non-trivial in cohomology (i.e. those that cannot be made equivariant by adding a suitable constant).

Comment: @TobiasDiez where can I read more about these examples, specially the one related to diffeomorphism groups?